# Rewrite URL to get rid of wp-content etc and change URL

Tags: url-rewriting, woocommerce-offtopic, urls, htaccess

I am trying to get rid of WP folders and rewrite URL for my custom PDF created a document based on ID of the product. I used the code below but it's not working.

Initial value: 
`http://example.com/wp-content/themes/exampletheme/templates/pdf-generator.php?productID=11`

The value I am trying to get: 
`http://example.com/carPDF=11`

**CODE:**

```
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    add_rewrite_rule('carPDF=([0-9]+)/?$', 'wp-content/themes/exampletheme/templates/pdf-generator.php?productID=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```

I was able to figure out myself, but now I get permalink like `http://example.com/carPDF/?productID=61` I want to remove get parameter and instead have the only number like this `http://example.com/carPDF/61`

**CODE UPDATED:** 
*functions.php*

```
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_pdfURL');
function custom_rewrite_pdfURL() {

    add_rewrite_rule('^carPDF/([^/]*)/?', 'wp-content/themes/exampletheme/templates/pdf-generator.php?productID=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```

F*orm.php*

```
<form method="GET" action="http://example.com/carPDF/" id="hidden-pdf-form">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo "$id"; ?>" name="productID">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></i>
    <input type="submit" value="Download PDF" class="btn btn-link"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you update the permalinks after adding the new rewrite rule?

Comment: Yep currently I was able to achieve this `http://example.com/carPDF/62?productID=62` I want to get rid of `?productID=62`. @kero I am using hidden form to pass get parameter with action attribute: `action="http://example.com/carPDF/<?php echo "$id";?>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$matches[1]` doesn't work for external redirects, only internal (URL must start with index.php and handled by WordPress itself)

Try this

```
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_pdfURL');
function custom_rewrite_pdfURL() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^carPDF/([^/]*)/?', 'wp-content/themes/exampletheme/templates/pdf-generator.php?productID=$1', 'top');
}
```

Don't forget to flush permalinks

Comment: It works, thanks, I can access the URL directly but when I am trying to enter it via link (in form via get attribute) it adds `?productID=62`. Any idea how to change this?

Comment: You don't need `<input name="productID">`... You can have `<form action="http://example.com/carPDF/<?php echo "$id"; ?>">` or just skip the form and have `<a href="http://example.com/carPDF/<?php echo "$id"; ?>">`